# How heroku hosting is build of ? and how can it support so many languages project to host it?

Tags: web, heroku, hosting

i just want to know how heroku tech stack built it to support so many languages hosting?

Just curious...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Buildpacks. You can also create your own custom buildpack. You can also combine different buildpacks together as long as they don't collide with each other. [Here is a custom buildpack](https://github.com/NNTin/heroku-buildpack-calibre/blob/master/bin/compile) which installs [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). This is the [official Python buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/main/bin/compile) (however it is a bit harder to understand)

Comment: Thanks for the ans, anything more do i need to know?